# PhpStorm no autocomplete when using getInstance method of a Class

Tags: phpstorm

[image: PhpStorm autocompletion]

Can somebody tell me why the autocompletion doesn't work when I'm using a `getInstance()` method instead of new ClassName?

Following is the `getInstance()` method of the class:

```
// Define The Namespace For Our Library
namespace JUnstoppable;

class JUnstoppable 
{
    // Instance Of The Class
    protected static $instance = array ();

    public static function getInstance ($forPlatformName = 'joomla')
    {
        $forPlatformName = strtolower($forPlatformName);

        if (!isset(static::$instance[$forPlatformName]))
        {
            static::$instance[$forPlatformName] = new \JUnstoppable\JUnstoppable($forPlatformName);
        }

        return static::$instance[$forPlatformName];
    }

    public function __construct ($platformName = 'joomla')
    {
    }

    public function doExecute ($test = 'lalala')
    {
        return $test;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can somebody tell me why the autocompletion doesn't work when I'm using a `getInstance()` method instead of new ClassName?

That's because IDE does not know what can be inside your `$instance` static property and therefore it cannot figure out what `getInstance()` returns. From IDE point of view it's just plain array (elements of any types) and not an array of `JUnstoppable` instances.

You can place caret on `$test` and invoke `View | Quick Documentation` to see what IDE knows about that variable. If it does not say `JUnstoppable` there then no wonders.

---

Just add proper type hint for return value of `getInstance()` method via **PHPDoc's** `@return` tag:

```
/**
 * My super method.
 *
 * @param string $forPlatformName Optional parameter description
 * @return JUnstoppable
 */
public static function getInstance ($forPlatformName = 'joomla')
```

You can specify concrete class (`JUnstoppable` in this case) .. or `static` if this method will be used by child classes as well and they will return different instances.

---

Alternatively (or better say: in addition) you can typehint `$instance` property which IDE will use to figure out what `getInstance()` method returns:

```
/** @var JUnstoppable[] Instance Of The Class */
protected static $instance = array ();
```